# iOS swift webview spaces in file name

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS programing. I have created a web view and now I'm trying to display my pdf file in the web view. Everything is fine if my file name is a single word, i am able to load the file in the web view. when my filename contains spaces in it, the application crashes when it tries to load the file. Thanks in advance if anyone can help me regarding this. Below is my code. plz let me know if any additional information needed.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mywebview: UIWebView!
var appdel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = "http://iracegcc.com/wallet/\(self.appdel.fileName)";
    var  urlString :String = url.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:urlString)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    mywebview.loadRequest(request)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Did you try going the other way, that is: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only escape the filename, not the entire url. ANd you should actually escape the string - your code removes (non-existing) escapes.

```
let url = self.appdel.fileName.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

var  urlString :String = "http://iracegcc.com/wallet/\(url)"
let requestURL = NSURL(string:urlString)
```

Comment: Hi Dear thanks alottt for the response. I have used the above solution as you suggested. getting same error I'm pasting it here. this error occurs only when the filename is more than one word and has spaces in file name.          Mineral Radiance Bilingual.pdf
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I updated the code, please try again! If that does not help, the error message would be key to solving your problem.